# Get AzureWebJobsDashboard through KeyVault

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-keyvault

As I have read, Azure Webjobs SDK requires the value of AzureWebJobsDashboard to be defined in the connection string section of an App Service. If I do that manually by going to the portal, and configuring the values, my webjob works fine.

What I want now is to provide the value of the connectionString in KeyVault and provide a secretURI provided by KeyVault in the ApplicationSettings of the App Service. Thereafter, I want the SDK to parse the secretURI and obtain the secret stored underneath in KeyVault.

I have tried to do this but am not able to get a definite solution for this. Is there any way to do this, or is currently not supported ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example of what Mike suggested:

```
var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

if (config.IsDevelopment)
{
    config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
}
else
{
    var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
    var vaultBaseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyVaultUri"];
    var client = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

    config.DashboardConnectionString = client.GetSecretAsync(vaultBaseUrl, "DashboardConnectionString").Result.Value;;
    config.StorageConnectionString = client.GetSecretAsync(vaultBaseUrl, "StorageConnectionString").Result.Value;;
}

config.UseTimers();

var host = new JobHost(config);
```

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication

Comment: Whilst the above code allows me to run the web jobs fine, the Kudu dashboard then complains that it can't find the AzureWebJobsDashboard connection string that has been removed. Were you able to get the Kudu web jobs dashboard working using the DashboardConnectionString  property from Key Vault?

Comment: I haven't used it with Kudu. I'm afraid it might require connection string to be present in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

WebJobs SDK will **not** automatically get from KeyVault.

But you could also fetch from keyvault yourself and then programmatically set the result on the JobHostConfiguration.Dashboard property.

You could file a request here to have more direct integration:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk